# access members in a 'has-a' relationship by other members of composition

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a class (composition) (has-a relationship) as follows:

The `class AP` is a bigger class that contains object of `class A`. `AP` also has a `state` variable as its member.

Problem: Can I access `AP's member 'state'` inside other composition members? (i.e. inside object of type `A`)?

Here is the code

```
class A {
 int i;
 public:
  void set(int x)
  { i = x; }

  int get()
  { return i; }

  void process()
  {
    cout << ::this->get() << endl; //// how to access AP's state variable here ?
  }
};


class AP
{
  A a;
  int state;

 public:
  void process() 
  {     a.process();   }

  void set()
  { state = 1; }

  int get()
  { return state; }
};



/// AP contains (or owns an object of type A)
/// I need to access AP's state value in object of type A (which is ap's member)

int main()
{ 
 AP ap;  //
 ap.set(); // set state value for AP
 cout << " get " << ap.get() << endl;  // get state value for AP


 ap.process(); /// calls a.process --> this must access ap's state value    


return 0;
}
```

There are solutions possible such as :

1. passing reference to itself and then access the value.
2. just simply pass the value of `state` in process() function. ( `ap.process(state)` )

But I want to know whether I can directly access member variables of a class in other members which have a composition (has-a)  [ see `class A::process()` method.

Comment: How is this question related to inheritance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking is "can I use 'is-a' concepts on objects designed with 'has-a' concepts"?

***The short answer***, no.

***The long answer***:
Sometimes, but only if it's static. Otherwise, 'A' cannot access non-static members of 'AP' without a context.

```
class A {
public:
    int p;
    void process() {
        p = AP::as; /* static object, okay! */
        p = AP::ap; /* compiler error, where's the instantiated AP to go along with it??? */
    }
};
class AP {
public:
    int ap;
    A a;
    static int as;
};
```

The "static" modifier puts the specified object to be a singular instance. Remember that when you start working with threads: all threads use the *same* instance which introduces data races! Case in point: `errno` prior to c++11; there is plenty of google references on the headaches from `errno` and threads. So because there's only one instance of `AP::as`, your `A` knows exactly where to find it (and might even be the first to access it).

But since `AP::ap` does not have the static modifier, it must have an instance of `AP` instantiated. Accessing it like shown above will result in a compiler error because the compiler doesn't know where to find the `AP::ap` object. It needs an `AP`. So this is where you'd provide a reference *to an already-instantiated `AP`* as such: `AP obj; p = obj.ap;` (or however other way you decide to provide an instantiated `AP` such as through a reference or a pointer or whatever).

All of this is because, given the idea that there could be *zero, one, or multiple* `AP` objects in existence (`AP aap; AP bap; A a; a.process();`, exactly which one did you mean you wanted? Example:

```
int main() {
    A a;
    a.process(); // Now what should 'a' try to access since there is no instantiated version of 'AP' ?

    AP aap;
    AP bap;
    a.process(); // Okay now there are two APs... which one did you want 'a' to access?
}
```

"Has-a" concepts which are quite different from "is-a" concepts (and in fact "has-a" concepts are **NOT** inheritance as you have tagged this question!).

Comment: static isn't the only way.  A can take a const AP reference "parent" in its constructor, AP initializes it with *this.

Comment: Yes you're right. Of course, @Pogo already mentioned that in his question (passing a reference to itself).

Comment: Yeah. Both the ways (passing reference to itself and passing state value directly) are possible and I mentioned them in the questions. Only if that variable is static, it can be accessed. Otherwise it is not possible as such and compiler will give error.

Answer (score 0):

You could give A a const reference to its parent AP, but if you simply want A::process() to use parent.state as an input, the easiest solution is to give it state as an input!

```
class A {
  void process(int state);
};

class AP {
  A a;
  int state;
 public:
  void process() {a.process(state);}
};
```